# Python - Get relative path of all files and subfolders in a directory

Tags: python

I am searching for a good way to get relative paths of files and (sub)folders within a specific folder.

For my current approach I am using `os.walk()`. It is working but it does not seem "pythonic" to me:

```
myFolder = "myfolder"
fileSet = set() # yes, I need a set()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myFolder):
    for fileName in files:
        fileSet.add(root.replace(myFolder, "") + os.sep + fileName)
```

Any other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with os.walk?  It's a first-class part of the library.

Comment: Well, there is nothing wrong with it I guess. But it didn't seem so "right". I am not familiar with python and its standard library, that's problem :)
But all answers gave some useful suggestions on how to improve my snippet.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Use [`os.path.relpath()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath).  This is exactly its intended use.

```
import os
root_dir = "myfolder"
file_set = set()

for dir_, _, files in os.walk(root_dir):
    for file_name in files:
        rel_dir = os.path.relpath(dir_, root_dir)
        rel_file = os.path.join(rel_dir, file_name)
        file_set.add(rel_file)
```

Note that `os.path.relpath()` was added in Python 2.6 and is supported on Windows and Unix.

Comment: Up for using `os.path.relpath()` instead of string manipulation.

Comment: using list comprehension (which is faster and more pythonic):
`files = [os.path.relpath(os.path.join(dirpath, file), rootDir) for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(rootDir) for file in filenames]`

Answer (score 11):

```
myFolder = "myfolder"
fileSet = set() 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(myFolder):
    for fileName in files:
        fileSet.add( os.path.join( root[len(myFolder):], fileName ))
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is perfectly right and I think should be done that way, BUT just for the sake of alternative, here is an attempt

```
import os

def getFiles(myFolder):
    old = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(myFolder)

    fileSet = set()

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(""):
        for f in files:
            fileSet.add(os.path.join(root, f))

    os.chdir(old)
    return fileSet
```

Answer (score 3):

I think os.walk is the right choice here.
maybe `root.replace(myFolder, "")` should change to `root.replace(myFolder, "", 1)` to avoid potential sth. you know.
If you already get the files and (sub)folders, [os.path.commonprefix](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix) worth a look too.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the third parameter for replace().

Comment: Also, don't use `+os.sep+`, use `os.path.join`.

Answer (score 2):

Thats probably the best way to be honest: you can use `glob` to go a certain number of layers down, but if you need it to be recursive you have to `walk`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [os.listdir()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) if you are just searching for an alternative to your solution.

But basically the logic will stay the same: iterate over the files - if directory, iterate through the subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
import pathlib

def find_path_to_file(file_name):
    globa_path = pathlib.Path.home()
    for path in sorted(globa_path.rglob('*')):
            if str(file_name) in str(path):
                return str(path)
```