# python os: get all absolute file paths under a certain directory

Tags: python, operating-system, os.walk

I have the following folder structure:

```
Desktop
├── dir1
│   ├── dir2
│   │   └── file4.pdf
│   ├── file2.pdf
│   └── file3.pdf
└── file1.pdf
```

I'm trying to return all of the files with their paths relative to the current working directory (Desktop). Based on my example above, I want:

```
Desktop/file1.pdf
Desktop/dir1/file2.pdf
Desktop/dir1/file3.pdf
Desktop/dir1/dir2/file4.pdf
```

This is what I have so far but it's not recognizing the nested directories:

```
import os
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/Users/Me/Desktop'):
    for file in filenames:
        print os.path.abspath(file)

# /Users/Me/Desktop/file1.pdf
# /Users/Me/Desktop/file2.pdf
# /Users/Me/Desktop/file3.pdf
# /Users/Me/Desktop/file4.pdf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filenames` is just a list of the names of the files, and doesn't store any directory information. That comes from `dirpath`, which you're ignoring at the moment.

```
import os
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/Users/Me/Desktop'):
    for file in filenames:
        print os.path.join(os.path.relpath(dirpath, '/Users/Me/Desktop'), file)
```

Edit: added `os.path.relpath` to give relative rather than absolute paths. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13617120/1669475).

Comment: Thos gives him the absolute paths, still a little bit more work to do, to get the relative paths, as requested by the OP.

Comment: Got it now. Much appreciated